# 24201 error when calling a stored procedure that gets db items that are at a certain distance based on latitide and longitude

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

When I call on a stored procedure like so:

```
decimal radius = 300; //these variables would normally be paramaters
decimal lat = 51.5466135m;
decimal lon = 3.511869m;

var vacatures = db.Database.SqlQuery<Vacature>("EXEC spVacaturesByRadius @pRadius, @pLat, @pLon", new SqlParameter("pRadius", radius), new SqlParameter("pLat", lat), new SqlParameter("pLon", lon)).ToList();
```

I get the next error message:

```
 {"A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate \"geography\": \r\n
System.FormatException: 24201: Latitude values must be between -90 and 90 degrees.\r\n
System.FormatException: \r\n
    bij Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.GeographyValidator.ValidatePoint(Double x, Double y, Nullable`1 z, Nullable`1 m)\r\n
    bij Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.Validator.BeginFigure(Double x, Double y, Nullable`1 z, Nullable`1 m)\r\n
    bij Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.ForwardingGeoDataSink.BeginFigure(Double x, Double y, Nullable`1 z, Nullable`1 m)\r\n
    bij Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.CoordinateReversingGeoDataSink.BeginFigure(Double x, Double y, Nullable`1 z, Nullable`1 m)\r\n
    bij Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.ParsePointText(Boolean parseParentheses)\r\n   
    bij Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.ParseTaggedText(OpenGisType type)\r\n   
    bij Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.Read(OpenGisType type, Int32 srid)\r\n   
    bij Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.ParseText(OpenGisType type, SqlChars taggedText, Int32 srid)\r\n
    bij Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.GeographyFromText(OpenGisType type, SqlChars taggedText, Int32 srid)\r\n."}
```

I've tried switching lat and lon's values because for people who've had the same problem as me that was often the solution but not for me.

The definition of spVacaturesByRadius =

```
      CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].GetItems_ByRadius
    (
     @pLat DECIMAL(20, 13)      --= 35.151
    ,@pLon DECIMAL(20, 13)      --= -86.59
    ,@pRadius DECIMAL(7, 2)     --= 2
    )
    AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        /*Declare Local Variables to avoid parameter sniffing*/
        DECLARE @Lat VARCHAR(20) = @pLat
           ,@Lon VARCHAR(20) = @pLon
           ,@Radius DECIMAL(7, 2) = @pRadius
           ,@Earth_Radius INT = 6371000

        /*Declare additional variables that are needed for calculations*/   
        DECLARE @Distance DECIMAL(10, 2) = @Radius * 1609.344
           ,@Point_geo GEOGRAPHY
           ,@Min_Lat DECIMAL(20, 13)
           ,@Max_Lat DECIMAL(20, 13)
           ,@Min_Long DECIMAL(20, 13)
           ,@Max_Long DECIMAL(20, 13)

        /*Convert original Lat Long parameters to GeographyPoint this will be used to check radius distance*/
        SET @Point_geo = GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText('POINT(' + @Lon + ' ' + @Lat + ')', 4326)

        /*Build Bounding Box*/           
        SET @Min_Lat = @Lat - DEGREES(@distance / @Earth_Radius)
        SET @Max_Lat = @Lat + DEGREES(@distance / @Earth_Radius)    
        SET @Min_Long = @Lon - DEGREES(@distance /

 @Earth_Radius / COS(RADIANS(@Lat)))
    SET @Max_Long = @Lon + DEGREES(@distance / @Earth_Radius / COS(RADIANS(@Lat)));

    WITH    MyBoxResults
              AS ( SELECT *
                       ,GEOGRAPHY::STPointFromText('POINT(' + CAST(Geog_Long AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' '
                                                   + CAST(Geog_Lat AS VARCHAR(20)) + ')', 4326) AS GeogLocation
                    FROM MyTable
                    WHERE ( Geog_Lat BETWEEN @Min_Lat AND @Max_Lat )
                        AND ( Geog_Long BETWEEN @Min_Long AND @Max_Long )) \
/*Using Long and Lat decimal columns we get results that are within the box that surrounds radius*/
        SELECT *
            FROM MyBoxResults
            WHERE @Point_geo.STDistance(GeogLocation) <= @Distance; 
/*This further limits results to only the radius instead of original box.*/

END
```

So what could be the matter?

p.s. Am I asking this question clearly enough? If not, what information is missing?

Comment: What is the definition of `spVacaturesByRadius`?  Are you sure the parameters are in the right order?

Comment: Just updated the question by adding the definition

Comment: You were right, I didn't pass the paramaters in the right order. That fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your input parameters in the wrong order:

```
var vacatures = db.Database
                  .SqlQuery<Vacature>("EXEC spVacaturesByRadius @pLat, @pLon, @pRadius"
                                     , new SqlParameter("pLat", lat)
                                     , new SqlParameter("pLon", lon))
                                     , new SqlParameter("pRadius", radius)
                  .ToList();
```

If you add parameters to a command of type "stored procedure" then the parameters are aligned by name, however you're using a text command that calls a stored procedure using `EXEC`, so the parameters are passed in the order they are in the command.

Comment: In my case leaving out EXEC didn't make a difference. But making the parameter order match that of the SP did. So thanks!